# Read only connection derby sql

Tags: database, connection, derby

my database properties changed to read-only connection, I'm able to read from the tables of the database. But I am not able to insert/update the tables.

The Error : 
[image]

please advise how to change the connection to read-only off.

Comment: Are you using Derby, or MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

One simple step to flip flop the Read lock in Apache Derby

READONLY { ON | OFF }

Source : https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.2/tools/rtoolsijcomref61092.html

Comment: The OP says he was using Derby, but you answered for MySQL.